# Java: Sorting a Queue of Objects

Tags: java, sorting, object, queue

I'm studying for an upcoming test, and came across a rather interesting problem. I'm attempting to order a queue of employees inside an array of objects, `Books`. I'm trying to order them in from highest to lowest based on the employee's priority.

```
class Employee{
String name;
int waiting_time;
int retaining_time;
int priority;
Book aBook;
ArrayList <Book> booksRead = new ArrayList<Book>();

public Employee()
{
    this.waiting_time=0;
    this.retaining_time=0;
}

    public int getWaitingTime()
{
    return waiting_time;
}

public void setRetainingTime(int retainingtime)
{
    retaining_time = retainingtime;
}

public int getRetainingTime()
{
    return retaining_time;
}

public void setPriority()
{
    priority = waiting_time - retaining_time;
}

public int getPriority()
{
    return priority;  //sort on
}


}

class Book{
String name;
LocalDate start_date;
LocalDate end_date;
boolean archived;
Queue<Employee> Employees = new LinkedList<>();

public Book()
{

}

//getters and setters omitted
public void setQueue(Queue<Employee> qa)
{
    Employees = qa;
}

public Queue<Employee> getQueue()
{
    return Employees;
}
}
```

My idea was add all of the elements in the queue, all the employees, into an ArrayList, sort them, and then push them one at a time back into the queue, but that doesn't work due to multiple errors. Any and all help is much appreciated!

My idea

```
public static void reorder(ArrayList <Book> booksToCirculate)
{
    ArrayList <Book> tmp = new ArrayList <Book>();
    for (Book b : booksToCirculate)
    {
        tmp.add(b);
    }
    tmp.sort(b.get); // I wanted to sort on the priority here, but i'm not sure how to
}
```

Comment: _due to multiple errors_ Do you want to clarify that?

Comment: What were the errors?  Don't know what "queue of employees inside an array of books" means, either.

Comment: Shoot I thought I posted that code, one second

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis My last attempt had multiple, this one I'm just sort of lost on

Comment: @duffymo I have an array of books `booksToCirculate` each `Book` has a queue of `Employee`'s. I'm looking to sort those `Employee`'s inside of the queue on their `priority` in descending order; So first item too get poll'd would be the highest `priority`

Comment: What errors are you getting? Where?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis on this attempt it won't compile. Meaning the error is located at `tmp.sort(b.get);`

Comment: Look at the compiler output. It tells you what that error is and why it happens. Edit your question and post that information.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis "b cannot be resolved to a variable"

Comment: Read up on variable scope. Then read up on method invocation.

Comment: Also, don't post important details in comments. Edit your question to include them.

Comment: I remember doing something last semester where i put a comparable thing in my class, is that do'able here?

Answer (score 0):

I'd wonder why your `Employee` isn't `Comparable`:

```
public class Employee implements Comparable<Employee> {

    private int priority;

    public class Employee(int p) { 
        this.priority = p;
    }

    public int compare(Employee that) {
        return this.priority - that.priority;
    }
}
```